# Transmit data and use defs between classes without instances - possibly Singleton Pattern

Tags: python, class, singleton

Class2 is my main APP, which displaying list of buttons from favList. 
In displayLibrary I create button with Class1 Instance.
When user click a button (simulateButtonClick), I had to run duplicateNetwork function from Class1
there I'll do all required stuff to duplicate object in Maya and I want to add this material using Class2.addSlot function (because I got a lot of checking there and do not want unnecessary code.)

So the deal is to create those connections:
1. From Class2.displayLibrary -> create buttons with instance of Class1
2. When used Class2.simulateButtonClick -> goto Class1.duplicateNetwork -> goto Class2.addSlot
And the second one I the hardest one, because when I call duplicateNetwork from button, I'm calling the instance that I created before and its fine.
but when I want to comeback to Class2.addSlot I can not create instance. I have to use the only one I'm using from beggining.
thats why I'm trying to use Singleton.

I commented those 2 lines that cause errors.

```
favList = []
buttons = {}
favList.append("shader1")
favList.append("shader2")
favList.append("shader3")
favList.append("shader4")

class Singleton(object):
    _instances = {}
    def __new__(class_, *args, **kwargs):
        if class_ not in class_._instances:
            class_._instances[class_] = super(Singleton, class_).__new__(class_, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            # class_._instances[class_].__init__(class_, *args, **kwargs)
            class_._instances[class_].__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        return class_._instances[class_]

class Class1(Singleton):
    def __init__(self, name):
        print ("Just test if name is working: {0}").format(name)

    @staticmethod
    def duplicateNetwork(self):
        newMaterial = "shader8000"
        Class2.addSlot(newMaterial)

class Class2(Singleton):
    def __init__(self):
        print "Do something in Class2"
        self.displayLibrary()
        self.simulateButtonClick()

    def addSlot(self, shaderName=None):
        favList.append(shaderName)
        self.displayLibrary()

    def displayLibrary(self):
        for i,obj in enumerate(favList):
            # create button with Class1 Instance
            buttons[i] = Class1(obj)
            print("Shader library contains: {0}").format(obj)

    def simulateButtonClick(self):
        material = "Shader6000"
        # Simulate click for button "Shader1"
        buttons[0].duplicateNetwork(self)


run = Class2()
```

Now I got errors: 
buttons[i] = Class1(obj)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\kTools\singlethon.py", line 46, in <module>
    run = Class2()
  File "G:\kTools\singlethon.py", line 27, in __init__
    self.displayLibrary()
  File "G:\kTools\singlethon.py", line 38, in displayLibrary
    buttons[i] = Class1(obj)
  File "G:\kTools\singlethon.py", line 13, in __new__
    class_._instances[class_].__init__(class_, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Thats because In singleton I got class_ in else If. I also commented that line, but could you tell me why? I do not know why there is need to be *args **kwargs, I mostly know what they are, but no Idea why I need them in Singleton.

Second error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\kTools\singlethon.py", line 49, in <module>
    run = Class2()
  File "G:\kTools\singlethon.py", line 31, in __init__
    self.simulateButtonClick()
  File "G:\kTools\singlethon.py", line 46, in simulateButtonClick
    buttons[0].duplicateNetwork(self)
  File "G:\kTools\singlethon.py", line 25, in duplicateNetwork
    Class2.addSlot(newMaterial)
TypeError: unbound method addSlot() must be called with Class2 instance as first argument (got str instance instead)
```

And for this one, I got problem from the beginning. No idea how to solve it.

Comment: Could you provide a complete working example so we can more easily see what's wrong?
Using your code with `favoriteMaterial_UI.addSlot(shader)` commented gives me no error when running `RightClickMenuButton()`...
Also, which version of python are you using?

Comment: Sure this is my complete code sketch.  http://pastebin.com/4rPv3xDG   and QTutils to import http://pastebin.com/ANUVkX1D      You can run it in Autodesk Maya

Comment: Commenting a lot of things to make your code run on my laptop gives no error when creating `favoriteMaterial_UI`...

You also changed `__call__` to `__new__`, which makes more sense to me.

Please try to work out a **real** minimal working example without any unnecessary library (such as maya, shiboken, etc) that still displays the error troubling you so that everyone runs the same code.
Edit your post to replace the old code.

Comment: Ok I did as you asked, it's mostly what i started from in this topic (with little fixes from @KevinKelbie  Hope this would help, to help me :)

Comment: Ok, first of all I think you should have a look at some tutorials regarding [inheritance in python while passing arguments (super)](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/), as well as the use of the [`*args` and `**kwargs` keywords](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments).
If I understand correctly what you want to do, I don't think you need the singleton class. Have a look at my old post that I edited.

Comment: Thanks for articles I'll try them ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing the new edit, I think you just want a reference to `Class2` inside each `Class1` so this should do the trick (you probably don't need `Singleton`):

```
from weakref import proxy

favList = []
buttons = {}
favList.append("shader1")
favList.append("shader2")
favList.append("shader3")
favList.append("shader4")

class Class1:
    def __init__(self, name, parent):
        self.parent = proxy(parent)
        print ("Just test if name is working: {0}").format(name)

    def duplicateNetwork(self):
        newMaterial = "shader8000"
        self.parent.addSlot(newMaterial)

class Class2:
    def __init__(self):
        print "Do something in Class2"
        self.displayLibrary()
        self.simulateButtonClick()

    def addSlot(self, shaderName=None):
        favList.append(shaderName)
        self.displayLibrary()

    def displayLibrary(self):
        for i,obj in enumerate(favList):
            # create button with Class1 Instance
            buttons[i] = Class1(obj, parent=self)
            print("Shader library contains: {0}").format(obj)

    def simulateButtonClick(self):
        material = "Shader6000"
        # Simulate click for button "Shader1"
        buttons[0].duplicateNetwork()


run = Class2()
```

Comment: I see that in my code I can do some less complex calls, and I'll do that. I'm just learning and with no programming background its not always clear from the beggining.

You used static method, but you didnt call run any defs from class RightClickMenuButton in class favoriteMaterial_UI. When I try to do that I still got the same kind of errors. Even if I can use another structure, if you can please help me how to call defs between classes without creating new instances every time. Thats why I tried to use Singleton. Now I code you gave, I can delete Singleton and it will still work the same

Comment: (why are you passing parent, name, and *args, **kwargs to super calls?)

In this example they are not necessary, but they helped me to create UI in PySide for Maya

Comment: Okay, could you explain precisely what you want to do? What do you mean by "call defs between classes"? (try to edit your first post to make it clear for everyone)
Also please post the exact error you encounter (the **whole** message): as you see, neither Kevin nor me are getting any such thing...

Comment: Sorry guys that was so incomprehensible :) Already I understand a lot more because of your help. I totaly rebuilt my post and hope this time you will understand my problem

Answer (score 0):

Okay so i think i was able to fix it.
you just had `self` missing as an argument.

```
RightClickMenuButton.duplicateNetwork(self)
```

and when i ran it i got another error on line 27 so i fixed that by adding `self` again.

```
favoriteMaterial_UI.addSlot(self, shader)
```

so the final code is.

```
favList = []
favList.append("shader1")
favList.append("shader2")
class Singleton(type):
    _instances = {}
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            cls._instances[cls].__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            # class_._instances[class_].__init__(class_, *args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]

class RightClickMenuButton(object):
    __metaclass__ = Singleton
    def __init__(self):
        print("Sygnal z Init RightClickMenu")
        self.addMenuActions()

    def addMenuActions(self):
        print("Sygnal z  addMenuActions")
        self.duplicateNetwork()

    def duplicateNetwork(self):
        shader = "shader3"
        print("Sygnal z  duplikateNetwork")
        favoriteMaterial_UI.addSlot(self, shader)

class favoriteMaterial_UI(object):
    __metaclass__ = Singleton
    def __init__(self):
        print("Sygnal z  init favoriteMaterial_UI")
        self.displayLibrary()
        self.wymuszonyKlikPrzycisku()

    def wymuszonyKlikPrzycisku(self):
        print("click")
        RightClickMenuButton.duplicateNetwork(self)

    def addSlot(self, obj):
        favList.append(obj)
        self.refreshSlot()

    def displayLibrary(self):
        print("Wyswietlam liste:")
        for obj in favList:
            print(obj)

    def refreshSlot(self):
        print("Sygnal z  refreshSlot")
        self.displayLibrary()


c = favoriteMaterial_UI()
```

if this was not what you where looking for i hope someone else can assist you!:)

Comment: You got no errors? I got: line 38, in wymuszonyKlikPrzycisku
    RightClickMenuButton.duplicateNetwork(self)
TypeError: unbound method duplicateNetwork() must be called with RightClickMenuButton instance as first argument (got favoriteMaterial_UI instance instead)

Script output should be like:
Sygnal z  init favoriteMaterial_UI  /
Wyswietlam liste: /
shader1 /
shader2 /
click /
Sygnal z  duplikateNetwork /
Sygnal z  refreshSlot /
Wyswietlam liste: /
shader1 /
shader2 /
shader3

Comment: nope, im not sure why you are getting an error.
`Sygnal z  init favoriteMaterial_UI
Wyswietlam liste:
shader1
shader2
click
Sygnal z  duplikateNetwork
Sygnal z  refreshSlot
Wyswietlam liste:
shader1
shader2
shader3`
thats the output i got.

Comment: You got correct output. Maybe cause my python is 2.7? Whats yours?
I updated post with some new code, it is working for you? (just remember to uncomment buttonclick before check)

Comment: `super(favoriteMaterial_UI, self).__init__(parent) # remove parent` has an error and it says that __init__ takes no parameters. also when you paste the code in all i have to do is add brackets to the prints.